# ssh-add not recognizing my key passphrase

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I'm having a rather unusual problem on my installation which I can't find the answer. I created a new ssh key using `ssh-keygen`, and got it a passphrase. The key is working. Added to the hosts I want to connect, and when it asks for the passphrase, I type and it works.

So, as expected, I went to add it to the `ssh-agent`, but, this is happening:

```
ssh-add /home/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa:
Bad passphrase, try again for /home/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa:
```

It does not accept my passphrase. I tried copy-and-paste, same deal. Anyone has any ideals?

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was because I was trying to feed the key in Putty's `.ppk` format.

Exporting the key into OpenSSH format (e.g. via PuttyGen) and using that solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I would give you a +1, but now I have to search how to do that.

Comment: Turns out it was really easy to do via PuttyGen. I moded your answer with that little detail. Thanks.